# Prefix numbering in figure captions with S in ConTeXt

Tags: tex

I am compiling some figures as supplementary material and would like to have figure captions follow the convention:

Figure S1, Figure S2, Figure S3, …

How can I achieve this?

Minimal example:

```
\setuppapersize[A6]
\setupexternalfigures[location=default]

\setupcaptions[way=bytext]

\placefigure
    {Cow}
    {\externalfigure[cow][width=2cm]}

\placefigure
    {Another Cow}
    {\externalfigure[cow][width=2cm]}
```

Comment: The amount of attention this question (and answer) have received suggests that [tex.se] would be a better place for them.

Comment: I tried. But ConTeXt questions don't seem to be too much appreciated in the LaTeX world.

Answer (score 0):

```
\setuppapersize[A6]
\setupexternalfigures[location=default]

\setupcaptions[way=bytext, numbercommand=S]

\placefigure
    {Cow}
    {\externalfigure[cow][width=2cm]}

\placefigure
    {Another Cow}
    {\externalfigure[cow][width=2cm]}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.